# Setting a custom system date on the fly for PHP script

Tags: php, unix, date, system

We have a script that needs to function between two dates, so to test the script we need to change the UNIX system date to simulate the date conditions.

**PROBLEM**:
The problem is we have other systems running on the same server so we can't just change the UNIX system date.

**QUESTION**:
Is there a way to set the system date on the fly within PHP, for example using ini_set or another method?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not stub out whatever methods you're using to fetch date information instead? Seems like that might be simpler, but I guess that depends on how complicated your script is.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create two timestamps and work with them in your script?